# How to append a string variable in Jquery html elememt attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Please , I have a JQuery code when appends data to a div element sucessfully like this

```
 $('#conversation').append('<div id="receiver"><p><b>' + username + ':</b> ' + data + '</p></div><br>');
```

Now supposing I want to have an anchor tag which will have a hyperlink inside as an atrribute and I want to pass a variable to that href attribute not the link itself since I don't know the kind of link that will be sent. I have problems tring to append this.

```
 $('#conversation').append('<div id="receiver"><p><b>' + username + ': <a id="link" href="'+ data +"></a></p></div><br>');
```

This does not work. Any idea how to go about this.
This is my whole code snippet

```
socket.on('updatechat', function (username, data) {
//showing username and the message sent
var checkifdataisalink=data;
var check=checkifdataisalink.split('://')
if((check[0]=='http')||(check=='https'))
{
    $('#conversation').append('<div id="receiver"><p><b>' + username + ': <a id="link" href="'+ data +"></a></p></div><br>');
}else{
$('#conversation').append('<div id="receiver"><p><b>' + username + ':</b> ' + data + '</p></div><br>');
}
```

});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apart from the missing quote, your `or` part of the if condition was missing `[0]`. See below.

```
//For demo purposes only
var check = ["http", "other-part-of-the-url"];
var username = "user";
var data = "data";
// --;--

if(check[0] == 'http' || check[0] == 'https') {
    $('#conversation').append('<div id="receiver"><p><strong>' + username + ':</strong> <a id="link" href="' + data + '">' + data + '</a></p></div><br/>');
} else {
    $('#conversation').append('<div id="receiver"><p><strong>' + username + ':</strong>' + data + '</p></div><br/>');
}
```

Demo@[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lshettyl/6s21LL47/3/)

Comment: Perfect. Just working very well. Thank you so much. I am most grateful

Comment: can you please explain how to go about situations like this. Sorry to bother you.

Comment: Every situation is different. Paying close attention to what you do would be helpful. Please accept/upvote this answer if it helped you.

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
$('#conversation').append('<div id="receiver"><p><b>' + username + ': <a id="link" href="'+ data +"></a></p></div><br>')
```

into:

```
$('#conversation').append('<div id="receiver"><p><b>' + username + ': <a id="link" href="'+ data +'"></a></p></div><br>');
```

Just one `'` was missing after `data`

Comment: You should explain the change you made (which was replacing the double quote with a single on the final string block)

Comment: the moment i do this "'+ data +'" the whole code becomes invalid. this side ': <a id="link" href="'+ data +'"> if it is correct should  have the a id turn blue, the href as well but the whole ': <a id="link" href="'+ data +'"> turns green and it indicates a syntax error

Comment: It shouldn't do if all of the quotes (double and single) have a matching start and end.